# Re-Installing an unpublished purchased app?

Tags: google-play-store, installation, uninstallation

Can i install a purchased app from playstore even if its unpublished from store?
I know it will be displayed on my apps list, but i think we can delete apps from that list too.In that case how I can find the app and reinstall it..

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to just Google it and find a copy elsewhere on the internet.  If it's unpublished from the Play Store, you can't install it from there anymore.

Comment: Thank you IAmTheSquidward for the answer.I am a developer and this question is regarding our recent project, so i am sure the app is not available anywhere else, is its sure if its unpublished and deleted from my apps list then app is not available.I haven't purchased any apps yet, do there is any separate list for purchased apps..

Comment: Nope, there's one list. I'm pretty sure they just disappear from that list as well.